# How to deal with a uncommitted coworker, it affects my performance too

Tags: management, colleagues, deadlines

I am a back end developer for a data visualization tool. I have to work with a coworker who does the front end part.

We established the deadline date to the client (it is a internal client in a big company) and I finished the data process almost 4 weeks before the dead line, luckily

I said luckily because the deadline was this last friday and my coworker never finished her part, she had all her own calculated time and my remained time to finish and she never finished; The thing that bothers me is that she does not have the nerve to tell me, hey, I had this XYZ problem and I could not finish my part.

I am responsible for the project, but she has her own boss, should I talk with her boss? the client is fully aware that I'm finished the back end of the project and I do not know about the front end, but I'm responsible of the project, I am afraid that this can affect me

Actually, one of the reasons my last boss was fired, because he directly complained about this person and her work ethic

Should I talk to her, my own boss, her boss?

Comment: Your boss was fired for complaining about her work ethic?!  Was the complaining inappropriate or to the wrong person, or is your company all messed up?  That's a serious question, because it can affect what kind of answer we should give.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek it was not the only reason, lets say it was a set of many problems with him; but this particular problem was that, he directly confronted the boss of my coworker and this boss said, in other words that he can not surpass his management, like, getting involved in other people's management; so, to add information, I have to walk in eggshells with this boss

Comment: I'm getting a strong feeling we're only getting one side of the story here.

Comment: @solarflare about my ex-boss? or my problem in particular?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, we have a PMO area and she swore there she could finish the project this past friday

Answer (score 6):

If you're responsible for the project, then this should be an important lesson: always check in on people working on the project, to make sure there are no hold ups and they are making progress.  Don't wait until the project is due or nearly due to find out it's not getting done.

Since you need to be careful in how you talk to her boss, and it sounds like talking to her directly might be considered as exceeding your authority, your first option should be to talk to your boss.  You want to ask for guidance in how to approach the other team.

I suspect you will need to talk to her boss.  You should acknowledge that you should have kept closer tabs on the project (not on her, on the project).  Identify the resources you need to get the project done now, and why it is important to the company.  Don't say that she's lazy or put her down or say she should have let you know.  Just explain what you need now, that you do plan to keep closer tabs on the progress, so that any problems can be dealt with quickly, and ask what kind of help he and his team can provide.  If he isn't willing to provide help, then you'll have to go back to your boss and see if there are other resources you can use.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I talk to her, my own boss, her boss?

Talk to your manager, it's their role to be the buffer between you and anyone outside the team particularly if there is an issue.